# Does tastypie swagger have built-in Authentication?

Tags: django, tastypie, swagger

Is there a way to get swagger to use the `login_required` decorator? I have it on several views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def index(request):
    pass
```

Is there a way I can get swagger to use this as well? It automatically will redirect users to the login page and would be handy to have in place.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way?